# Prevent ElementTree.parse() from serializing newlines in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, elementtree

Does anyone know a trick for preventing serialization of newlines by ElementTree? In this situation it is useful to preserve some level of human readability of the source xml document by breaking up contents of a a long string of text over multiple lines. However, the output of parsing the file should treat this as a single line.

To illustrate: Given a file, tasks.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tasks>
    <task>
        <title>Work in a Button Factory</title>
        <description>Push
            the
            button
            with
            your
            left
            hand.
        </description>
    </task>
</tasks>
```

And read.py:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse("tasks.xml")
print root.find('./task/title').text
print root.find('./task/description').text
```

The current output is:

```
work in a button factory
Push
            the
            button
            with
            your
            left
            hand.
```

But it is desired that the output should be:

```
work in a button factory
Push the button with your left hand.
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you're looking for?

```
  desc = root.find('./task/description').text
  print ' '.join(desc.split())
```

It would be a little ugly to do a lot of that inline but you can easily wrap it up in a function:

```
  def oneline(elementText):
      return ' '.join(elementText.split())

  print oneline(root.find('./task/description').text)
```